# ServletRequestListener - Getting the userprincipal returns null

Tags: java-ee-6, embedded-jetty, servlet-3.0, basic-authentication

I'm having a web-application that is secured with HTTP-Basic auth. 
I also implemented a filter using the `ServletRequestListener` interface. Now when the filter calls the `requestInitialized` method, the getUserPrincipal-Method of the request returns null. But when I check the request headers, the authorization-header is set with the encrypted value. Here's the code:

```java
@Override
public void requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent e) {

  HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) e.getServletRequest();

  //p is null
  Principal p = request.getUserPrincipal();

  Enumeration<String> enH = request.getHeaders("Authorization");
  while (enH.hasMoreElements()) {
    String s = enH.nextElement();
    System.out.println(s);
    //prints. 
    //Basic c3RhY2tvdmVyZmxvdzpteXBhc3N3b3Jk
  }
}
```

Why is the userprincipal not initialized?

Comment: Some details on how you setup your embedded jetty would be useful.  Know that you will likely need to setup a LoginService + Constraint + ConstraintMapping + Roles + ConstraintSecurityHandler ... [example](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/SecuredHelloHandler.java)

Answer (score 2):

You are likely not setting up the needed security layers for embedded-jetty.

Here's an [example](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/SecuredHelloHandler.java) found in the [Jetty embedded examples source tree](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded).

```java
package org.eclipse.jetty.embedded;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintMapping;
import org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.security.HashLoginService;
import org.eclipse.jetty.security.LoginService;
import org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.BasicAuthenticator;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Constraint;

public class SecuredHelloHandler
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Server server = new Server(8080);

        LoginService loginService = new HashLoginService("MyRealm","src/test/resources/realm.properties");
        server.addBean(loginService); 

        ConstraintSecurityHandler security = new ConstraintSecurityHandler();
        server.setHandler(security);

        Constraint constraint = new Constraint();
        constraint.setName("auth");
        constraint.setAuthenticate( true );
        constraint.setRoles(new String[]{"user", "admin"});

        ConstraintMapping mapping = new ConstraintMapping();
        mapping.setPathSpec( "/*" );
        mapping.setConstraint( constraint );

        Set<String> knownRoles = new HashSet<String>();
        knownRoles.add("user");
        knownRoles.add("admin");

        security.setConstraintMappings(Collections.singletonList(mapping), knownRoles);
        security.setAuthenticator(new BasicAuthenticator());
        security.setLoginService(loginService);
        security.setStrict(false);

        // Your Handler (or Servlet) that should be secured
        HelloHandler hh = new HelloHandler();

        security.setHandler(hh);

        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using a Filter instead of a Listener..

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = { "/*" })
public class RequestFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
        FilterChain fChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest hReq = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    //p is not null anymore
    Principal p = hReq.getUserPrincipal();
    fChain.doFilter(hReq, res);
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
}
}
```